# Incorrectly spelled name on international flight ticket

Tags: air-travel, transit, paperwork

I've booked my ticket using a travel agent. My full name is `Muhammad Adeel Mustafa Janjua`. The agent said the word length of my name exceeds the length limit so he used `M` instead of `Muhammad` and now it appears on the ticket as `M Adeel Mustafa Janjua`.

Would I face any issues at the airport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you I have a big name and airlines always screw up with names. I don't think it should be a problem, if someone ask you can explain the same reason you stated. I don't think they care that much about every letter of names.

Comment: thanks mate.
i was quite worried because i haven't travelled on air before so this relaxed me alot.

Comment: Sure, have a nice journey.

Answer (score 5):

You should not have any problems. It is common to use just initials when the name is too lengthy. If you are too concerned then just take your credit or debit card that you used to buy the ticket with you and present at the time of check in if they ask you.

My own name is pretty long but not as long as yours and I have used just my initials for air tickets on more then one occasion when the lady on the other end was having a hard time understanding my name and it did not cause any problems.

Comment: thanks alot.
Atleast i'm not the only one with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Though its not your primary concern, even most of my visas do not carry my own given name, i.e. the printed version does not show it, it gets cut off. My full passport name is 8 characters longer than yours, and shortening of 2 parts of my name is the common solution I arrive at for the purpose of airline tickets, while visas print as much as they can.

As suggested in the other answer carrying the credit card used for booking , any other documentary proof showing your name in its full and shortened forms may help convince a few people, though it is only to make things easier.